# How to get SKSpriteNode subclassed object back from click

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclassing

I have the following Object I have subclassed from SKSpriteNode

```
class PlayingCard : SKSpriteNode
{
  var suit:Int = 0
  var rank:Int = 0
  var visible:Bool = false

  init()
    {
        super.init(
         texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "card.png"), 
         color: NSColor.blackColor(), 
         size: SKTexture(imageNamed: "card.png").size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func updateSprite()
    {
       if (suit == 1 && rank ==1) 
       { self.texture = SKTexture(imageNames: "ace_of_clubs.png") }
       .
       .
       .
       .
       // A bunch of switches and if's to assign the right image
    }
}
```

Now I initialize this class and add it to my scene. Everything works fine, the card shows up. Except when I look for `self.nodeAtPoint(location)` after a click, I get a `SKNode` back!! Are all my values lost? Whats going on here?

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) 
{
    // Called when a mouse click starts
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    let t = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    NSLog("%s",String(t.suit)) //<-------- Won't Compile
}
```

Any idea how to do this? Trying to type cast using: `t as! PlayingCard` builds the project but I get gibberish printed in Log.

Here are the enums and the PlayingCards class:

```
enum Suits:Int
{
    case Diamond, Heart, Club, Spade
}

enum Ranks:Int
{
    case ace, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king
}

class PlayingCards : SKSpriteNode
{
    var CardRank:Ranks = Ranks.ace
    var CardSuit:Suits = Suits.Club
    var Visible:Bool = false
    //var Sprite:SKSpriteNode

    init()
    {
        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "b1fv.png"), color: NSColor.blackColor(), size: SKTexture(imageNamed: "b1fv.png").size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func updateSprite()
    {
        self.name = Description(Set: 2)

        if self.Visible
        {
            self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: generateSpriteFilename())
        } else {
            self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "b1fv.png")
        }
    }

    func generateSpriteFilename() -> String
    {
        return self.Description(Set: 2) + ".png"
    }

    func Description(Set s:Int) -> String
    {
        var cr = ""
        var cs = ""

        switch self.CardRank
        {
        case .ace:
            cr = (s == 1) ? "ace" : "1"
            break
        case .jack:
            cr = (s == 1) ? "jack" : "j"
            break
        case .king:
            cr = (s == 1) ? "king" : "k"
            break
        case .queen:
            cr = (s == 1) ? "queen" : "q"
            break
        default:
            cr = String(self.CardRank.rawValue + 1)
        }

        switch self.CardSuit
        {
        case .Club:
            cs = (s == 1) ? "clubs" : "c"
            break
        case .Diamond:
            cs = (s == 1) ? "diamonds" : "d"
            break
        case .Heart:
            cs = (s == 1) ? "hearts" : "h"
            break
        case .Spade:
            cs = (s == 1) ? "spades" : "s"
            break
        }

        return (s == 1) ? cr + "_of_" + cs : cs + cr
    }
}
```

Here is how I populate the array:

```
func prepareDeck() -> [PlayingCards]
    {
        var deck = [PlayingCards]()

        for i in 0...3
        {
            let s:Suits = Suits(rawValue: i)!
            for j in 0...12
            {
                let r:Ranks = Ranks(rawValue: j)!
                let c:PlayingCards = PlayingCards()
                c.CardRank = r
                c.CardSuit = s

                deck.append(c)
            }
        }

        return deck
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th method `nodeAtPoint` does return you an `SKNode`.

Of course we know that node could be more specific but at compile time all we can say is that it will be an `SKNode`.

Now, if you believe that the object is something more specific that a simple SKNode (like a `PlayingCard`) you can try to cast the node to your type.

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if let playingCard = node as? PlayingCard {            
        // here you have your PayingCard object!
        print(playingCard.suit)
    }
}
```

In the code above, the body of the `IF` is entered only if the retrieved node is a `PlayingCard`. In this case a new constant `playingCard` having the type of `PlayingCard` is created.
So inside the body of the `IF` you can use all the methods and properties you defined in your `PlayingCard` class.

Comment: It still returns gibberish "¿ŒT". Does nodeAtPoint actually return the original object? or just the SKNode part of it?

Comment: It returns the full object. I don't understand what you mean. Does it enter the `IF`?

Comment: It does. Here is what I am using: `if let playingCard = node as? PlayingCard {NSLog("%s",String(playingCard.suit.rawValue))}` (in my project suit is actually an enum). Here is what I get in the Log: `2015-11-28 10:58:05.376 PlayingCards[28602:2653744] ¿ŒT`

Comment: Well then I think we solved the first problem. Next problem is why `playingCard.suit.rawValue` produces `¿ŒT`. Please show me how the enum is defined and how you are populating the `suit` property.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried NSLog right after populating the PlayingCards class instance and I got the gibberish back. So I am probably not filling it out right. Please see edit for enums, class and how I populate it.

Comment: Ok please replace your `NSLog` invocation with `print(playingCard.suit.rawValue)`.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you! It was the %s in NSLog. I should've used %@! Thank you so much for working with me on this!